# file permissions and group ownership using sftp

Tags: permissions, file-management, user-accounts, sftp

Is there a way to have all files created by a particular user under *sftp* to have a specific group and file permissions? The user in question, of course, will be a member of the group, but it is not his primary group. In other words, is there a way for sftp to automatically duplicate the effects of umask and newgrp?

Comment: Also search for options to do this with scp. Unfortunately, there is confusion between scp - sftp - ftps - ftp-ssl

Comment: Seems like more of a ServerFault question to me, but it could be a grey-area.

Answer (score 5):

There is such thing as a *subsystem* in (Open)SSH: it is a program which gets lauched when you request something other than interactive shell. Technically it is just an executable on remote host which is `exec`'d by `sshd` child after authenticating you and calling setuid.

You can locate a standard subsystem definition for `sftp` in your SSH config:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

As it is just a plain executable, not a SUID one or special in any other way, you can write a shell script that will change any attributes you need and then just launch original subsystem handler.

Place the following script into `/usr/lib/openssh` folder as e.g. `sftp-fperm-server` (this is not required, just to keep things in one place):

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 026
exec /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Then add a line in the end of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem sftp-fperm /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-fperm-server
```

And then restart `sshd` (it does not kill sessions on restart) and launch `sftp` with a `-s sftp-fperm` option. Voila! files get the new specified umask.

If you do not want to specify that option each time, just change the standard subsystem definition. Interactive sessions won't be affected by it, so there are no chances of breaking somthing.

If you want to use the `newgrp` command, things will be a bit trickier. `newgrp` always launches a new interactive shell while stupidly don't allowing to pass any parameters to it, so you can't use it as the `umask` in previous example. But you can replace the last line in script with:

```
SHELL=/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server newgrp git
```

Actually calling the `newgrp` for some group I belong to emits a password request, so I was unable to check this solution (I mean only the `newgrp` one), but it works when I pass the `/bin/id` on my laptop (without SSH), so if you got `newgrp` working for user no problems should arise.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what whitequark is saying, you could build a solution along those lines but use the "sg"-command in place of newgrp, which is a kind of "su" for groups. Look it up as "man sg" on any linux system, at least.

Answer (score 2):

`chmod g+s directory`
Will grant ownership to the user's group for all directories & files created in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this is server specific. Check the server configuration for potential configuration options.

Comment: Well, it is the sftp program which comes with OpenSSH (under linux). It is just not obvious to me how to do what I want, totally transparent to the sftp user.